# Android- changing theme in specific Activity

Tags: android, android-theme, android-switch

The base theme for my app is:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabView</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyMenu</item>
        <!--<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/window_action_bar_style</item>-->
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

and I would like to apply this theme to just one activity.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
</style>
```

However when I do this, I am unable to access the SwitchCompat widget in that activity:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat/>
```

What am I doing wrong here ? Any suggestions or a solution would be most appreciated. The problem occurs when I try to override the base theme in a particular activity and try to access the SwitchCompat widget. My project is already quite large for me to change my base theme for the entire application as I will have to make changes to the ActionBars and other views. How can this be solved ?

Comment: you are using appcompat? and also having this `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light`. Should you be not using appcompat derived theme everywhere?

Comment: No, this is exactly what I feared. I am not using appcompat and I've been looking for a workaround in just one specific activity. I guess I'd have to change the base theme and make changes to entire application then.

Comment: in that case i don't understand why you would use switchcompact

Comment: That is because I would like to use Material Design switches in just one activity instead of the default switches.

Comment: natively its available in lollipop. so if you want material in the other (below lollipop) versions you need to use appcompat.

Answer (score 13):

Just use your custom theme like this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".SignupActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_signup"
    android:theme="@style/SignupTheme">
</activity>
```